# Opening a .zbd file

Tags: file-format

I have a .zbd file from my military service with sensitive information on it from 2004.

I have downloaded the ZoomBrowser from Canon, it does not recognize it as a file.

I downloaded the Zebedee Secure Tunnel, but that just creates a tunnel, and is not a file viewer.

I have downloaded a number of free file viewers, but none seem to open this file.

Any assistance you could give is immensely appreciated.

Comment: What does `file` say? What is the output from `strings`? What if you just look at it with a text viewer? What size is the file? Apparently it is not anything to do with Canon and I fail to see the reason to install Zebedee...

Comment: I don't think this is a retrocomputing question. I always post questions of this type on superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://fileinfo.com/extension/zdb says 
File Type 2 EPSQ Database

with description:

Encrypted file format used by the U.S. military and Department of Defense for Electronic Personal Security Questionnaire (EPSQ) documents; most often used for the Standard Form (SF) 86 Questionnaire, which is used by military personnel, government employees, and government contractors to apply for a Security Clearance.

That seems like what you're looking for.

According to this site and several like it there's a Windows program "DoD EPSQ" that can read this.

According to https://dmna.ny.gov/arng/ocs/epsq_directions.pdf that software can be downloaded from https://sclient.dss.mil/download/w95nt.htm, but that website no longer exists.

Another person had a similar question here: https://www.airwarriors.com/community/threads/looking-for-the-epsq-software.34223/
but not sure if the linked dropbox file is correct (or safe).
Good luck.

Comment: And a silly comment - I would expect any sensitive information to be protected with a password. Do you know it?

Comment: @tum_ I would guess the "password" is more likely to be authorizing access to the system where the files are stored, not a password for each individual file. (Having worked in an environment with a fairly low level of military security, the first level of "password" is the lock on the office door to get access to a computer that is connected to a secure network...)

Comment: @alephzero Hmm, reading the question again: "I have a. zbd file" implies the OP already has it in their possession. To be honest, though, I feel a bit uncomfortable even discussing military stuff on a public resource))